# Rails Nested Attributes - Not all validations being triggered and only on update of an existing record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 5 app and have an `Expenditure` model:

```
  has_many :expenditure_items, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :expenditure_items, allow_destroy: true
```

validates_associated :expenditure_items

with a related `ExpenditureItems` model:

```
  validates :budget_item_id, presence: { message: "Budget Item required" }
  validates :cbs_item_id, presence: { message: "CBS required" }
  validates :wbs_item_id, presence: { message: "WBS required" }
  validates :description, presence: { message: "Description required" }
  validates :quantity, numericality: { message: "Quantity must be a decimal number" }
  validates :unit, numericality: { message: "Unit must be a decimal number" }
```

I have a nested form and I can see the paramaters being submitted:

```
"expenditure_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"budget_item_id"=>"", "wbs_item_id"=>"5", "cbs_item_id"=>"6", "description"=>"qweqwe", "quantity"=>"1.0", "unit"=>"234.00", "_destroy"=>"false", "notes"=>"", "id"=>"49"}, "1"=>{"budget_item_id"=>"5", "wbs_item_id"=>"77", "cbs_item_id"=>"5", "description"=>"TEst", "quantity"=>"1.0", "unit"=>"1000.00", "_destroy"=>"false", "notes"=>"", "id"=>"47"}}
```

yet the controller doesn't throw a validation error with `budget_item_id` nil. Now if I clear out any other required field the validation triggers along with the `budget_item_id` validation (i.e. the edit renders and I get the browser validation errors).:

```
"expenditure_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"budget_item_id"=>"", "wbs_item_id"=>"5", "cbs_item_id"=>"6", "description"=>"", "quantity"=>"1.0", "unit"=>"234.00", "_destroy"=>"false", "notes"=>"", "id"=>"49"}, "1"=>{"budget_item_id"=>"5", "wbs_item_id"=>"77", "cbs_item_id"=>"5", "description"=>"TEst", "quantity"=>"1.0", "unit"=>"1000.00", "_destroy"=>"false", "notes"=>"", "id"=>"47"}}
```

I understand I could add:

```
validates_associated :expenditure_items
```

This works and my form validates but I lose all the nested validation errors and just get a generic 'not valid' error.

Now I tested this with a new nested attribute and the validation triggers correctly - so only this happens when I have an existing record.

Am I missing anything obvious here?

Comment: Do the values on the associated expenditure change? Is it possible that it is failing quietly?

Comment:  hmmm...that may be it.  In my case I was changing some logic.  Before this particular field was optional and now required.  So this record in particular has "" or `nil` currently and the form is sending the same value.  I might set this form up so that by default the select passes a character or "0" and force the update.

Comment: Or do a quick rake task to set the default if currently nil.

Comment: I could do that - in my case I expect the user to never hit this situation in the real world but I want to ensure 'just in case'.